# serialize 2d form element into object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a method on stack a while back that allows me to convert a forms elements into an object, here is the method:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

This works well for most forms but now I have run into an issue where it doesn't seem to handle input arrays, for example:

```
<input type="email" name="email[0]['address']" id="email" />
<input type="hidden" name="email[0]['type']" value="Support"/>
```

Can anyone help me modify this method to allow for multidimensional array inputs?

Thanks a mill